# how to add strings together?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, math

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cushioncheckBox.Checked)
    {
        decimal totalamtforcushion = 0m;

        totalamtforcushion = 63m * cushionupDown.Value;
        string cu = totalamtforcushion.ToString("C");
        cushioncheckBox.Checked = false;
        cushionupDown.Value = 0;
    }

    if (cesarbeefcheckBox.Checked)
    {
        decimal totalamtforcesarbeef = 0m;
        totalamtforcesarbeef = 1.9m * cesarbeefupDown.Value;
        string cb = totalamtforcesarbeef.ToString("C"); 
        cesarbeefcheckBox.Checked = false;
        cesarbeefupDown.Value = 0;

    }
}
```

So i have these codes. How do i add the two strings, cb and cu together? I've tried doing

```
decimal totalprice;
totalprice = cu + cb;
```

but it says the name does not exist in the context.
What should i do??

i'm using windows form btw

Comment: Why are you using string variables if your performing Math?

Comment: Declare your strings outside of your `if` statment. And strings != decimals, you will need to convert them.

Comment: because i want to put the total value in a textbox at the end!

Comment: @user2037510 So? Do the math on the decimals and the convert to text. There is no need to convert the numbers to strings, then to decimal only to convert to text again.

Comment: @user2037510 it is much easier to convert a number to a string than a string to a number... thus you should do the math with a number-type (double, int, float, decimal) and make the output via conversion `Convert.toString(totalprice)`

Comment: i tried doing this 

            string totalprice;
            totalprice = cb + cl;
            totalamttextBox.Text = totalprice ("C");

but it says that the totalprice is a variable but is used like a method. how do i rectify this?

Comment: totalprice.ToString("C")

Comment: Your trying to access variables that exist only within your If Statements mate there not accessible outside if that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues here:

First of all, your `string cu` is declared inside the `if` scope. It will not exist outside that scope. If you need to use it outside the scope of the `if`, declare it outside.

Second, math operations cannot be applied to `string`s. Why are you casting your numeric values to string? Your code should be:

```
decimal totalamtforcushion = 0m;

if (cushioncheckBox.Checked)
{
    totalamtforcushion = 63m * cushionupDown.Value;
    //string cu = totalamtforcushion.ToString("C"); You don't need this
    cushioncheckBox.Checked = false;
    cushionupDown.Value = 0;
}

decimal totalamtforcesarbeef = 0m;
if (cesarbeefcheckBox.Checked)
{
    totalamtforcesarbeef = 1.9m * cesarbeefupDown.Value;
    //string cb = totalamtforcesarbeef.ToString("C");  you don't need this either
    cesarbeefcheckBox.Checked = false;
    cesarbeefupDown.Value = 0;

}

var totalprice = totalamtforcushion + totalamtforcesarbeef;
```

Comment: Along with this answer you need to learn about displaying your numbers as string, check out this MSDN page, it will help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: Just to be explicit, since this seems like a novice question. The var keyword, in this case, evaluates to a decimal. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx if you are confused. You can then use totalprice.ToString("C") like you were before to get the string form. You can also make totalprice a decimal if you prefer, it works out exactly the same.

Comment: string result = totalprice.ToString("f2"); Will give your anser to 2 decimal places. Or simplerm totalamttextBox.Text = totalprice.ToString("f2");

Comment: @Derek: I think he wants it to display as a currency though.

Comment: totalamttextBox.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", totalprice);

Answer (score 0):

In general, to "add" two strings (where you're really trying to find the sum of two numbers):

1. Convert your two strings to numbers.
2. Add the numbers.
3. Convert the sum to a string.

Pretty straightforward; but feel free to ask if you have any further questions.